# By what can we extend a Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension) talks about Lie algebra extension by a Lie-algebra, while [this other artilce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Cohomology_in_small_dimensions) talks about extension by a module. [This nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+algebra+extension) mensions central extensions by a [ground field](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ground+field).

Are they all some special cases of something, or are they different concepts?

Comment: At least the ground field would be a special case of a module. The circle group makes no sense to me, I assume you or your source mixed up Lie algebras and Lie groups there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Oops.. you are right, $\mathbb T$ is for group extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly one can extend Lie algebras by Lie algebras. Here the ground field is considered as a $1$-dimensional abelian Lie algebra. For example, we have the short exact sequence of Lie algebras
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\rightarrow K \rightarrow 0,
$$
where $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ is an extension of $K$ by $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$.

In the second link, $M$ is a Lie algebra module, but it is
in fact considered as an *abelian Lie algebra* in the short exact sequence. So this is not different.

The second Lie algebra cohomology $H^2(L,M)$ classifies equivalence classes of *abelian* extenions
$$
0\rightarrow M \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow L \rightarrow 0,
$$
i.e., where $M$ is an abelian Lie algebra. See for example this post:

[Classification of Lie Algebra extensions in Weibel's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195168/classification-of-lie-algebra-extensions-in-weibels-book)

and other related posts.